# UnZip the downloaded file in same folder using Swift language in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

After downloading a file, how can one extract the file in the same directory using swift language? I am new  to iOS development and need some detailed explanations. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [this](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) library for unzipping on iOS.

If you check their documentation, you can see this method for unzipping:

```
SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(zipPath, toDestination: unzipPath)
```

Also they have an example [here](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive/tree/master/SwiftExample).